# how to get update the pickerview of one class from another class without using singleton classes or static?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

how to get update the pickerview of one class from another class without using singleton classes or static ?

only we have to use delegate.

here i have

class one{

pickerview;

pickerview.delegate=self;

pickerview.datasource=self;

}

class two{

here from how can i uptade the first class pickerview data.

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) technique to raise a notification and use `addObserver:selector:name:object:` to attach a method in class one to update picker view as required.

Answer (score 0):

The most common mechanism to notify about something without delegates is NSNotification. Check docs for [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). Briefly: you register listeners for the appropriate event and fire notification when that event occurs.